# Formatting of strings in .desktop files

Tags: kde, desktop, .desktop

I have *accidentally* noticed that on my machine (running KDE) fields of desktop entries (those little `.desktop` files used to make desktop icons and such) may contain some simple HTML-style formatting, like `<i>` or `<b>` tags. They actually get properly displayed with bold or italic text. I have tried some other tags and attributes, but they don't work.

```
Name=<i>Heli</i><b>X</b>
GenericName=Go fly
```

[image]

1. Is this a somewhat standard feature? Where is it documented? (Not in the [desktop entry specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html)).
2. Where can I get the full list of supported tags and attributes?

Comment: Could you show us an example? I tried adding `<i>` and `</i>` around the title field of a .desktop and Cinnamon just displayed it. Might be a KDE-only feature, but it would be easier to test if you showed us an example.

Comment: @terdon added a screenshot